# Askew div transform

Tags: css

First - I have to apologise for really bad question. I know that questions like this shouldn't be here, but I really have no idea what else should I do now. Because I've tried to google this issue and also was searching here. But no result.

The thing is - I have to make page exactly like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37BCj.jpg
I have all the background images separately, because it should work that non-active div will be covered with dark filter and onhover it will colorize. So I would like to ask, if is that even possible? To make divs askew like this? With `transform: rotate` maybe? I will be SO MUCH thankful for every help how to solve this. 
Thanks for your help and sorry for this type of question.

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/pen/yOwvQV)

Comment: @APAD1 wow thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, note that this solution uses [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) click the link to see browser compatibility